# PHP form submit and form data validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, form-submit

In PHP is this enough to guarantee a form has been submitted by clicking the form submit button and to verify the content posted is not empty?

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty($_POST['field_data']))
{
echo "ok";
}
```

Comment: you can add a `isset($_POST['your_submit_button'])`

Comment: You just simply can check for `if(isset($_POST['field_data'])) {
echo 'ok';
}`

Comment: isset does half the work !empty does   :-)

Comment: But Attention: There is allways a way to fake an button click with javascript, you cant be sure that your user clicked on the submit button, allways keep this in your mind ;)

Comment: @ReeCube: this is true, but by verifiying $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] I can say the form was submitted.

Comment: @3000 yes, but you cant say if it was an robot or if it was an human and you cant say if it was a click or an javascript too, thats what i meant

Comment: @ReeCube: oh, sure, sorry  :-)

Comment: `$input = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'field_data', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, there may be a way to be sure the form was submitted using your form.
If I would like to do it, I think I will make something like this :

```
$secure = $_SESSION['form']['submit'] = MD5(time());
```

```
<form>
<input type='hidden' name='secure_form' value='<?php echo $secure ?>' />
</form>
```

And else when submitted check the value :

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['secure_form']) && $_SESSION['form']['submit'] ==  $_POST['secure_form']) {
  //do stuff
}
```

Of course, you have to add `session_start()` at the top of the page!

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use a hidden form field

```
<?php
$csrf_token  = md5(time().'random string');

$_SESSION['csrf'] = $csrf_token;

?>
<input type="hidden" id="submitted" name="submitted" value="yes"/>
<input type="hidden" id="csrf" name="csrf" value="<?php echo $csrf_token; ?>"/>
```

Then in my PHP I'd use something like:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && $_POST['submitted'] == 'yes' && $_POST['csrf'] == $_SESSION['csrf']){
   // Do something
   echo 'Form submitted via POST';
}
```

Updated to include a CSRF field

Comment: $_POST['submitted'] can throw an error if its not set ^^

Comment: hidden plain text field are easy to spoof.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` output so best way to convert output in upper

```
if(strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'POST') {
```

Then you can check with submit button name also like

```
<input type="hidden" id="submitted" name="submitted" value="yes"/>

if(strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])=='POST'  && isset($_POST['submitted']) && $_POST['submitted'] == 'yes'){
```

also you can check all values of form which will be submitting by `isset()` or `empty()`